# php generate token synchronized based on time stamp

Tags: php, random, token

this is a question a little complicated, I do not know how I will respond,but i try.
how can I generate a random token in php every 30 seconds applies for each client making a request to the server php where is running this script?
For example:

User 1 connect to server at 17:30:10 and the token is ABC

User 2 connect to server at 17:30:33 and the token is always ABC

the token must be changed every 30 seconds.
how can i implements this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you're token when connecting, save that in a `file` or `database` save the datetime or timestamp too. If there is another load, check if the time has a difference of 30 seconds. Ifso, update the db values and the random key.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the token into cache, or file, dB and set the expiration time to 30 sec

Comment: how can i implements this? explain please

Comment: You can use Memcached. It's a hash table available for all users, check if $omemcached->get('token')!=false then you have it if not generate new and $omemcached->set('token', $token);

Comment: At end you need some kind of storage available for all users, it could be memory, cache, file system, daemon, etc.

Comment: You can use nginx proxy cache to create an Webservice generating tokens with lifetime 30s.

Comment: For nginx cached proxy webservice check this: http://wiki.nginx.org/ReverseProxyCachingExample for Memcached: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php for apc: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php